Forget stored data when the browser is quit
I am saving a cookie, or localstorage, or sessionStorage item "chatsession" - which I want the browser to remove when the browser is closed.
That sounds like sessionStorage right?
sessionStorage.setItem('chatsession', 'value');

what about cookies? I tried using SameSite:
document.cookie = `${name}=${value}; path=/; SameSite=Strict`;

However, when i quit firefox, and then restart it and choose "restore previous session", the chatsession item is there! How do I ensure the users security and really truely delete it on browser quit?
